# Plotting spectral profiles of features

Tags: r, plot

Hi I am plotting the spectral profile of each individual feature in the table below. For the road feature I am able to plot it but for the others I get this error. Please assist.
This is the code I used:

```
plot((sli[,1:3]),col="grey",type="l")
```

This is the error I got:

> Error in plot.default(...) : formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments

This is the table

[image: Features to plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plot` wants a vector and you give it a matrix. You could make an empty plot and `lines` afterwards by looping over the columns in an `sapply`.

```
plot(1:nrow(sli), type="n", ylim=c(0, max(sli[1:3])))
sapply(1:3, function(x) lines(sli[x], col="grey", lty=x + 1))
```

[image]

Or simply use `matplot` which is designed for this purpose.

```
matplot(sli[,1:3], col="grey", type="l")
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
sli <- data.frame(41:47*.01, sample(200:900, 7), sample(20:90, 7))
```

Comment: @CharityMaphanga I'm happy to hear that! In this case you may accept the answer now, see how it works: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)